# How to find item with less sub items number in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have tons of `UL` lists. Each list contains items wrapped within `LI` tag. I would like to get the count of the list with less items than others.

Something like this works fine, but how can I do this in on line?

```
var total = 100000;
$('ul').each(function(index, item) {
  var len = jQuery(item).find('li').length;
  if (len < total && len >1) 
    total = len;
})
return total;
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you wish to cut the code down to one line?

Comment: Filter perhaps plus Math.min would be something to apply

Comment: There's no way to do this in your (rather odd) 'one line' requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is as small as I can get it

```
$('ul').each((_,ul) => min = Math.min(min,$("li",ul).length))
```

```js
let min = $('ul > li').length; 

// Without arrow

$('ul').each(function() { min = Math.min(min,$("li",this).length) })
console.log(min)

// With arrow
$('ul').each((_,ul) => min = Math.min(min,$("li",ul).length))
console.log(min)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: As I said, very great solution. But I would switch `let min = $('ul').length;` by `$('li').length;`.

Answer (score 1):

This will save you at least one line:

```
var total = 100; // A high value is set because you want to look for the minimun lenght
$('ul').each(function(index, item) {
  if (jQuery(item).find('li').length < total) total = jQuery(item).find('li').length;
})
return total;
```

As you can see, with this code if you have a `lu` with zero `li` it will return that `lu`. Just add the second condition to solve it.

If you really need to have it with less lines you can write it like this, it's the same but with less lines.

```
var total = 100; // A high value is set because you want to look for the minimun lenght
$('ul').each(function(index, item) { if (jQuery(item).find('li').length < total) total = jQuery(item).find('li').length;})
return total;
```

You can save the `var total` adding a new parameter. For example I'm gonna use the method call `func()`:

```
function func(var total=100) {
    $('ul').each(function(index, item) { if (jQuery(item).find('li').length < total) total = jQuery(item).find('li').length;});
    return total;
}
```

Comment: in one line please

Comment: @Bellash But why ? There is really no improvemt to get from this

Answer (score 0):

You can write this in one line - only the "tidy" makes it in three :)

```js
const liLength = Object.entries(document.getElementsByTagName('ul')).reduce((acc, curr, index, array) => {
  return (acc > array[index][1].children.length ? array[index][1].children.length : acc)
}, 100000)
console.log(liLength)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
</ul>
```

This is a pure JavaScript ES6+ function, that makes use of `Object.entries()`, and `reduce()`.

Answer (score -1):

You could sort your jQuery object by number of children `<li>`, then get that number of the first `<ul>` of the list.

I put it on three lines for readablity, because it is quiet long for a unique one. If you **really** need **one** line, remove line returns.

```js
let min = $('ul').sort((a, b) =>
  ($(a).find('li').length - $(b).find('li').length))
.first().find('li').length;

console.log(min);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Clearly, but I didn't find shorter/more readable when I was thinking about it... But your solution is nice!